# SELECT IF THEN ELSE statement

Tags: mysql

I want to do query like this

```
SELECT if(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM application WHERE id_student=1 
AND ap_status<>"Wysłano" AND date(app_date) > (SELECT tax_year FROM const_data)),
(SELECT * FROM application WHERE id_student=1 AND ap_status<>"Wysłano" AND date(app_date) > (SELECT tax_year FROM const_data)),
(SELECT * FROM application WHERE id_student=1 AND date(app_date) > (SELECT tax_year FROM const_data)))
```

But true or false value should contain one column. Is it possible, to make this in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even sure if what you tried would execute, but this should accomplish what that looks like it is trying to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM application 
WHERE id_student=1 AND date(app_date) > (SELECT tax_year FROM const_data)
ORDER BY ap_status="Wysłano" 
LIMIT 1
```

This will fail if `const_data` has more than one row though.

---

Edit: Hmm, this answer is not quite right if you expect multiple records. At this point, the best solution is to remove the limit and handle the results in whatever code processes these results. It CAN be done in a single query, but I generally wouldn't recommend it.

---

Edit2: Sidenote... if `app_date` is a datetime, you may see performance boosts by removing the use of the `DATE()` function and instead converting `tax_year` to a datetime.

---

Edit3: Last one, I promise.... probably. In the case where it must be done in one query, and results cannot be processed after, this should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM application 
WHERE id_student=1 AND date(app_date) > (SELECT tax_year FROM const_data)
   AND IF(EXISTS([that query]), ap_status<>"Wysłano", TRUE)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know, but const_data have only one row

Comment: `ORDER BY` should be `DESC`

Comment: @Barmar Nah, he has preference for `<>` rows, which sort earlier (false) in an `=` comparison; but yeah, I always do a double take every time I write something like that.

Comment: @Barmar I know it and I improve this

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that you inverted the sense of the comparison from his query.